# why does cnn accuracy show only 0.3~0.4

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I wrote very simple cnn code with spectrogram images, but
the accuracy is only 0.3~0.4

What do i have to add the other option to improve accuracy?

````
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=X_train.shape[1:], padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
# model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
# model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())    
model.add(Dense(64))   
model.add(Dense(32))
 
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(14))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))```
````

Comment: Do you normalize the spectrograms? What are the classes?

Comment: Yes i normalized images and  i have 14 classes. I tried to multi label classfication.

Answer (score 1):

With the information you provide, there is zero chance to help you with the problem. The definition of your model looks correct (but you missed an activation function after the first dense layer if this is by accident). So here are some considerations:

1. Do you train long enough? Your model is quite big and therefore needs a long time to converge AND a large dataset to train with.
2. Is your dataset large enough and contains enough variance? When your dataset doesn't represent your problem well, you can't train.
3. Take a look at the Loss curves of your validation AND training set. Are you overfitting/underfitting?
4. Do you correctly normalize and preprocess your dataset? Try to transform the values of the images to a range of -1 to 1 or 0 to 1 with a float datatype.
5. Is your dataset balanced? As you are softmaxing 14 classes, you need a balanced dataset in order to train every single class.

Hoped this helped a little, if you need further help please provide some detailed descriptions of your problem and what are you doing in your whole process.